# Using a action's result - Pt. 2

Tags: ros, action, ros-kinetic, action-server, action-client

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello together,

I already had a [problem](https://answers.ros.org/question/309975/using-a-actions-result/) using the result of an action.

After implementing the solution of @mgruhler, another problem occurred.

This time I have another problem: The `result` is defined in the action file and consists of several float values:

- `translationx`
- `translationy`
- `translationz`

I would like to see the result by using `ROS_INFO("X value: %f", result.translationx)`.

Unfortunately the compiler says: `DetectionResult has no member named 'translationx'.`

---

EDIT

The full action file is:

#goal definition
float64 ObjectID

---
#result definition
float64 translationx
float64 translationy
float64 translationz

---
#feedback
bool isProcessing

---

In the following you see the C++ source code within the `main` function:

```
bool finished_before_timeout = ac.waitForResult(ros::Duration(30.0));

if (finished_before_timeout){
    actionlib::SimpleClientGoalState state = ac.getState();
    manipulator::DetectionResultConstPtr result = ac.getResult();
    ROS_INFO("Action finished: %s", state.toString().c_str());
    ROS_INFO("X Value: %f", result.translationx);
}
else{

    ROS_INFO("Action did not finish before the time out.");
}
```

`ac` is the action client.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/310345/using-a-action%27s-result---pt.-2/) by [waltejon](https://answers.ros.org/users/38851/waltejon/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5 on 2018-12-10

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2018-12-10**:
can you please show your full action definition? This seems to be a non-standard ROS action. This will help in debugging.

Please don't edit anything (except for maybe removing comments).

**Comment by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) on 2018-12-10**:
Can you post your full source (or at least all of this that's relevant) we can't help you much from a single line. The same goes for the compiler error, the full error text is far more useful.

**Comment by [waltejon](https://answers.ros.org/users/38851/waltejon/) on 2018-12-10**:
The full action definition is added to question above. The design in the comment section is suitable, so I edited my original question.

**Comment by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) on 2018-12-10**:
Thanks for the update. But your c++ source is more important in this case, sorry if I wasn't clear.

**Comment by [waltejon](https://answers.ros.org/users/38851/waltejon/) on 2018-12-10**:
Now I added the source code too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`result` is a `manipulator::DetectionResultConstPtr`. Note the **ConstPtr** part. Thus, it should be `result->translationx`, most probably.

I'm a bit confused about the compiler error, though. Thus, I'm basically seconding @PeteBlackerThe3rd :-) Copying the compiler error with relevant context (and not typing) helps here...

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2018-12-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [waltejon](https://answers.ros.org/users/38851/waltejon/) on 2018-12-12**:
Thanks again for your support! Now it works.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm far from 100% sure on this but try:

```
ROS_INFO("X Value: %f", result.result.translationx);
```

I think the result object may contain additional header and goal information with the result that you've defined within the action in a separate result property.

Let us know if it works.

---

Originally posted by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) with karma: 9529 on 2018-12-10

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1